# How to get the id of clicked mat-button instead of mat-button wrapper?

Tags: angular-material, material-design, angular7

I am using **material** design in my **Angular7** project.There is a click event on  a mat-button.

```
  itemclick(event: Event) {
 //to know the id of clicked element,ie button
 let elementId: string = (event.target as Element).id;
 console.log(elementId);
 }
```

here is the HTML

```
<button mat-button color="primary" id="test1" (click)="itemclick($event)" style="outline: none">Property1</button>
```

But I dont get the id always, because the (event.target) keeps changing randomly between mat-button(case in which id=test1) and mat-button-wrapper(case in which id is null).

How to solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want the button Id every time?

Comment: Yes,Everytime I click on it.

Comment: <button mat-button color="primary" id="test1" (click)="itemclick("test1")" style="outline: none">Property1</button>--------------------- try this way its should work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace your function with:

HTML:

```
<button mat-button #test color="primary" id="test1" (click)="itemclick(test)" style="outline: none">Property1</button>
```

TS:

```
itemclick(event) {
   console.log(event._elementRef.nativeElement.id)
}
```

[`StackBlitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gdlmc3)